# Intel TBB libtbb.so file not found after upgrading

Tags: c++, ubuntu-18.04, tbb, tbb-flow-graph

I had a project running with older version of TBB (flow graph input_node was not declared), and I had no idea how to update it or how it was installed...
In the desperation of the moment I found: https://github.com/wjakob/tbb so I went a head and purged tbb using `dpkg --purge libtbb-dev` then followed the instructions in that git repo.

Now when I run the google tests to check that everything is fine, first couple tests that only use tbb pipeline works correctly.
For the following tests that use tbb flow graph builds correctly, when running I get this error message:

```
QueryExecuter_Google_Tests_run: error while loading shared libraries: libtbb.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I'm no expert in this field, tried googling around but never found anything that I understand, they all mention linking problem but shouldn't that be detect at build?

My cmake file is very simple:

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
add_executable(QueryExecuter_Google_Tests_run GlobalAlgorithmTest.cpp)
target_link_libraries(QueryExecuter_Google_Tests_run leveldb gtest gtest_main tbb)
```

Any idea what went wrong and how could I fix it?

running on Ubuntu 18.04.5
cmake

Comment: What does `ldd QueryExecuter_Google_Tests_run | grep tbb` say?

Comment: tbb is a part of c++. exec policy depends on it , so you do not need github there. install it as system lib

Comment: @JohnZwinck it says `libtbb.so => /usr/local/lib/libtbb.so (0x00007ff4cc6d2000)`